# How do I get YAML syntax highlighting in PyCharm?

Tags: yaml, pycharm

PyCharm doesn't seem to support YAML Syntax highlighting by default. Is there a plugin? I didn't see anything obvious when I Googled for one.

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html -- check **Platform** section. YAML available in Pro edition ONLY.

Comment: I am using the Community Edition so this is the answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

This works for me in the community edition:
   File -> Settings -> File Types -> Add a type for yaml

I didn't do anything else except set '#' as the line-comment character.

This colors basic names, values, strings and comments nicely.

[image]

If you can't find the option, search for "File Types" in the search box in the Preferences window.

Comment: In addition you can add your main keywords (keyword + colon) in the "Keywords" section.

Comment: `File -> Settings -> Editor -> File Types` in Professional edition.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to Settings
2. Code Style
3. Yaml

If you don't see this, you're probably using the community edition where I didn't find a way to get Yaml highlighting working.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the [YAML/Ansible support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7792?pr=pycharm_ce) plugin with PyCharm 4.5.1 Community Edition, and it's good enough for my basic needs:

> YAML/Ansible support with Jinja2 tags
>
> Based on NEON by juzna.cz
>
> Provides:
>
> - Index of all roles in Goto Class...
> - Index of all properties in Goto Symbol...
> - Reference Jinja2 variable declaration
> - Reference to role declaraion
> - Various completions
> - Documentation lookup
>
> This is a very basic version and needs a lot of polishing. Please help at the https://github.com/vermut/intellij-ansible