# PyCharm does not highlight yaml syntax

Tags: pycharm, yaml, styles, azure-pipelines-yaml

Seems that there is a problem with Pycharm (2021.3.3 Community Edition) with yaml files.

It cannot recognize yaml files if they have a '-' in the file name.

So PyCharm does not highlight keywords and syntax in files like 'configuration-file.yml', but it does with 'configuration_file.yml'.

I'm contacting PyCharm in order to report this problem, but in the meantime how can I force a single file to be parsed as a yaml?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967224/how-do-i-get-yaml-syntax-highlighting-in-pycharm).
Mine refers to a problem related to the file name, the mentioned question refers to a general problem on the 9-years old PyCharm version where the Yaml files were only supported in the Pro edition!

Answer (score -1):

While waiting to IntelliJ's answer, I've notice an item in the contextual menu of the file:

[image]

Here you can select the file type of the selected one.